# HELP upgrade from 12 to 14 can't log in PLEASE HELP

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

I have been running 12.whatever for a while, no problems. Today, I tried the upgrade to 14.04. The upgrade seemed to go fine. However, when I got to the log in screen, when I logged in it said "Error. report now?" or something.. and then it just hangs. I'm stuck at the purple log in style screen.

I looked up some solutions, Ctrl-Alt-F1'd, logged in, and at someone's suggestion did a "sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome". After installation and reboot, I no longer even get the Log In screen. After the "U B U N T U" loading screen it goes black. At this point, I can Ctrl-Alt-F1 and log in to a command line, but now what? I'm hosed!

Also, I would simply burn a copy of the 14.04 installation disk and run a new install because I have about 800 gigs of unpartitioned space on the HDD. Howver, there is some kind of issue with the sector size allocations; my Swap Space seems to be off by a few blocks and unusable. Every time I have removed and re-created the swap partition it adds about 1024 to the number of bytes the block is "off" by. So, I assume that adding a new installation will just hose things even more. Please Help!!!

In case anyone cares, my system is home built with an Intel Quad Core-Duo 2.6ghz, 4gigs DDR3, 3 hdds.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your 3 disks is not in use
* install ubuntu 14.04 onto that and
* put the bootloader on that disk, too.

In case you need some partitions on each disk, use `gparted` and
* try to move data to another partition or
* delete corrupt partitions (e.g. the swap?), create a separate one for `swap` and `/` and install there.

Maybe try [ubuntu gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/) if you prefer the gnome desktop.

As always, backup of data is recommended!